# contains entitlement values that are not supported

Tags: ios

Have created an app-id as normal.
Then created an app-store distribution profile...as normal.
Set up the game in itunes connect
Installed the profile
Built the game with GS...all goes fine.

But when I upload my binary is rejected with that error : Invalid Code Signing Entitlements

**Invalid Code Signing Entitlements :**
The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported. For the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement, the first value in the array must consist of the prefix provided by Apple in the provisioning profile followed by a bundle identifier suffix.

The bundle identifier must match the bundle identifier for one of your apps or another app that you are permitted to use as the iCloud container identifier.

```
Specifically, value "(my team bundle seed id is here).*" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" in basejumpxl is not supported.
```

Really not sure what I have done wrong...as I have done this loads of times, and never had this issue

Anyone point me in the direction of what my obvious mistake might be??

Comment: Can anyone verify if the problem is solved in Xcode version 4.1, like is said in this post http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21529?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally successfully submitted the app, and it's now "Waiting for Review" status.

The problem is with the new "Enable for iCloud" configuration in App ID's.
Here's what I did to fix it. Hopefully this will help anyone who's having this issue.

In iOS dev portal:

1. Save yourself some time and just go ahead and delete the provisioning file you previously made for the new app you're trying to submit. (you may have luck by simply renewing it, but probably not.)
2. Go to your App ID, and click on configure. Once in configure, UNCHECK "Enable for iCloud" and click "DONE". iCloud configuration is what's causing the error. (This option had disappeared earlier, but is back again.)
3. Make a brand new provisioning file for Appstore distribution, and select the proper app id.
4. Download this new provisioning file.
5. Add this newly downloaded provisioning file into Xcode's organizer. Easiest way is to just drag and drop the file overtop Xcode's app icon.
6. Re-publish your game in Gamesalad, making sure to choose the NEW provisioning file you just created. (I went ahead and deleted the problematic provisioning file so I didn't get confused and accidentally choose the wrong one when publishing.)
7. Re-submit through Application Loader.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Also works for Mac App Store submissions... Thank you so much!

Comment: Great that saved a life here. +1+1 thanx. But I am wondering how did you discover that?

Comment: I know this is old but this really helped me. Thank you