# ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Phonegap Build

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap

I get these errors with an App built with PhoneGap build. Looked for this issue with phonegap but couldn't find anything.

ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment' in 'Payload/LatInc.app/'."

```
    ERROR ITMS-90211: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported. For the 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers' entitlement, the values in the array must start with the prefix provided by Apple in the provisioning profile, followed by characters that are uppercase or lowercase Roman letters [A-Z, a-z], the digits 0 through 9, dot ['.'], or hyphen ['-'], and not contain any wildcard characters. Specifically, value '3222A74EAQ.*' for the key 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers' in 'Payload/.app/' is not supported."
    ERROR ITMS-90211: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported. For the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement, the value must start with the prefix provided by Apple in the provisioning profile, followed by characters that are uppercase or lowercase Roman letters [A-Z, a-z], the digits 0 through 9, dot ['.'], or hyphen ['-'], and not contain any wildcard characters. Specifically, value '3222A74EAQ.*' for the key 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier' in 'Payload/LatInc.app/' is not supported."
```

Comment: This resolved my problem. 
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656318/contains-entitlement-values-that-are-not-supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's issue in your package name is different than your provisioning profile package name (bundle identifier).

So please change the package name as bundle identifier.

Comment: Thanks, Hiten. I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Should the ipa be named as bundle identifier. Or is it in phonegap config.xml?

Comment: in your "config.xml" and your provisioning profile package name is different.
example :: config.xml --> com.demo.example and in profile --> com.example.
That's why the error occurred.

Comment: That was fine actually. This resolved my problem. 
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656318/contains-entitlement-values-that-are-not-supported